# MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Issue: Need to use Media Store API or No Access to Files

Tags: 3d

I have a problem with switching to the Android API version 30+.
The Google console rejects my updates referring to the fact that I use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, although I do not specify it anywhere in my manifests. The only thing I use is the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but judging by the Google documentation, it is not prohibited (I may be wrong, then please correct). But nevertheless, Google experts write that I use a shared access request and I can't understand why.

In my AndroidManifest I left only two permissions:

> ```
>     <!-- permissions - add/remove according to required functionality -->
>     <uses-android permission:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
>
>     <uses-android permission:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>     </manifest>
> ```

and it seems that the error has been fixed, but with every next release, they send the same message, no matter what I do.

It seems to me that the problem may be that I previously specified an important permission in the console (and there is still a declaration with the specified MAGAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE hanging there), and I cannot delete it or reset it. (there's just no button there, and you can't keep it empty either)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd0z0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxoZX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTTZ7.png)

Maybe someone has encountered this problem, I really ask you to help with its solution.

Comment: It seems that I solved this problem, I removed the WRITE_EXTERNAL_Storage permission from all available manifests and left only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and Google accepted the update. Moreover, the read permission is not indicated now in the apk data, although it is there and everything works fine. Reading and translating into texture works clearly.

But the recording stopped working after the user takes a screenshot in the application. It is not saved. I haven't solved the problem yet, as soon as I find a solution I will write.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error Google rejects my app 7-8 times and I'm not using any External permission to read and write.